# Typescript prevent assertions to a super type

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Is there a Typescript compiler flag such that the following code would not compile?

```
interface A {
    key: number
}    
var B = {} as A;
```

For any cases where the type of A extends B.  Such that for the above to compile, it would have to use double assertion: `var B = {} as any as A;`

Some other examples of this scenario where A extends B, yet it is allowed to assert that B is of type A.

```
class A {
    public key = 1;
}
var B = {} as A;               // Would not want to compile

declare var A: number | null;
var B = A as number;           // Would not want to compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's your final goal, but I can explain why the following code compiles:

```
interface A {
    key: number
}    
var B = {} as A;
```

TypeScript has a structural type system. You use an empty object {}, which is compatible with any other type. That's why no errors.

Still, try to describe your goals better.

Comment: Take this example `declare var A: number | null; var B = A as number;` This is allowed in typescript. This is an assert and not a cast, so at runtime, `A` could have the value of null, and could throw runtime exceptions using `B` presuming it cannot be null. So I'm asking if there is a tsconfig flag that will disallow attempts to assert B to A, if B is a subtype of A.

Comment: When you use the as–assertion in your example, you say to TypeScript, "Don't try to do type checking because I know better than you: A is a number."